# Shatranj puzzle by Aladdin - white to play and win

Tags: puzzles, shatranj

```
[Title "White to play and win"]
[fen "3qrb2/4k3/2p1NpRp/P3pPpP/2Pp2r1/BP1R1pP1/2Qnpr2/5B1K w - - 0 1"]
```

This is attributed to [Ala'Addin (aka Aladdin)](https://www.chess-poster.com/english/history/aladdin.htm).

Reminder, the [rules of Shatranj are here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/what-are-the-rules-of-shatranj/42024#42024).

Answer (score 1):

From *The Complete Chess Addict* by Mike Fox and Richard James

```
[Title "White to play and win"]
[fen "3qrb2/4k3/2p1NpRp/P3pPpP/2Pp2r1/BP1R1pP1/2Qnpr2/5B1K w - - 0 1"]

1. Rg7+ {Remember the shatranj bishop moves 2 squares diagonally so can't take the rook} Kd6 {The shatranj bishop is still defending the pawn on h6} 2. c5+ Kd5 3. Rd7+ Ke4 {The shatranj queen can only move one square diagonally so the rook can't be taken} 4. Re3+! Kxe3 (4...dxe3 5. Qd3+ Kxf5 6. Ng7#) (4...Kxf5 5. Ng7#) 5. Bc1+ {the shatranj bishop} Ke4 6. Qd3+ Kxf5 {the queen is protected by the f1 bishop!} 7. Ng7#
```

Nice that the replayer also works for shatranj.